# Using Start a List Workflow Action in App Step

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, designer-workflow, app-step

I activated the App Step and followed all the directions to give the site control. I added it to my workflow and I when I went to check for errors, I get this error.
"This workflow action is not supported in this region of the workflow. It can only be inserted in certain types of blocks."
Here is the stage where I placed the "Start a List Workflow" action inside of the App Step.
[image: App Step]

I removed the "Start a List Workflow" action from the App Step to test, and when I went to place it back, it was not included as an action to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow coordination actions (Start a List/Site workflow) are not supported in App step.

We can only add the coordination actions outside of the App step.